# copy database file from MyDocuments

Tags: java, sqlite

i have a sample code to copy a file from one location to another. am using that as a backup for an SQLite database file which copies the file from My Documents folder to the desktop.. the sample code is below:

```
try{
            DateTimeFormatter date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss");
            String sys =System.getProperty("user.home");
            String fileurl = sys+"\\Desktop\\school database backup";
            File dest = new File(fileurl+date.format(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()));dest.mkdir();


            String sys1 =System.getProperty("user.home");
            File source = new File(sys1+"\\Documents\\hyper-DB\\intellect");

            FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Backup Successful");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.getMessage();
        } finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }

        }
```

this code works perfectly on my my pc which I used to create the project. but when I install it on another user's pc. it doesn't work. and am sure its unable to locate the database in My Documents folder though its there. please what do I do to make it work on another pc. thank you

Comment: Any error messages ? I see What happens when you try to launch the path via Windows `run`  utility in the client machine ? Is the client machine user a Local User or an network user (i.e. Active Directory) ?

Comment: Any number of things could be causing the problem. You should change your `e.getMessage()` line to display the error message. For example `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

As with every programming problem there are multiple ways to solve the problem. I will try to explain a couple of ways I would solve your problem. If you are heck bent on using the copy function from FileUtils. Have the entire project in a dedicated folder, with all the files in, you can even have sub-folders, this will keep thing consistent and you won't have to worry about file permissions, like the ones found on school computers. Another way to achieve the same out come is to read the main database and copy the data to the backup database one element at a time. This can also let you have the main database in the same directory as the backup database. It wouldn't hurt to have it all in a single folder too.